# Receiving error: Reverse for with arguments '()' and keyword arguments not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am getting an error creating a link in my Django template.

My template looks like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'location_detail' pk=location.id %}">{{ location.name }}</a>
```

My urls.py looks like:

```
url(r'^location(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.location_detail, name="location_detail"),
```

My view looks like:

```
def location_detail(request, pk=None):
```

I get the error:

```
Reverse for views.location_detail with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 1L}' not found.
```

I'm using Django 1.5 and python 2.7.2

Thanks!

Comment: Remove pk= in the template call

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that I had a name space on the primary project urls.py:

```
url(r'^com/', include('com.urls', namespace="com")),
```

Changing the url to:

```
{% url 'com:location_detail' pk=location.id %}
```

That did the trick

Comment: Wow, I did not know about the namespace issue with reverse, and this post definitely did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You have given your url pattern a name, so you should use that name in the `{% url %}` call:

```
{% url 'location_detail' pk=location.id %}
```